# Laravel find(int) returns multiple records (Explain please)

Tags: laravel, eloquent, find

I don't really understand the find method.
There are two ways to use this method.

1) **App\Model::find(int primarykey)**

2) **App\Model::find([int pk1, int pk2,...])**

** Update **

Why do I get multiple results when I use find with a single primary key (the first way I described) combined with the get() method after that?

My solution is just simple not to use find for looking up a single record, instead I would use where('id',pk) or find([pk]) <-- which works

Comment: Do you somehow have duplicate values in your "primary key column"?

Comment: `find(pk)` will only return one record.

Comment: One problem is going to be, there is multiple entries in table with the same pk

Comment: Thanks for your replies guys,
I found out that find(pk) returns only one value.

Do you know why this method returns multiple value if you use find(pk)->get() ? 

Or why the method call first returns the first entry of the whole table?

It's probably wrong to call first or get, because you get receive a single record from find, but why does it work and returns a complete different record?

Comment: `->get()` will cast it to a `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection` instance.